# Set environment variable in Jenkins from command output

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, acr

Is it possible to set the output of a command to an environment variable in Jenkins? Something like this:

```
environment{
  ... 
  ...
  registryAddress=sh(az acr list --query "[?contains(name, 'myname')].name" --output tsv --resource-group myresourcegroup))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to use `returnStdout: true` when calling `sh`. 
 `registryAddress=sh(script: "<your-script>", returnStdout: true)`

Comment: Thanks it works, this is what I was looking for. Here the details for the docs: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script